# Django models and legacy class integration

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

If I have existing classes (generated off some UML model) from legacy code, what is the best way to integrate them with the Django **model classes**?

I have so far considered using the Django custom fields to serialize the class and let that handle persistence. (The disadvantage of this being that other applications accessing the database directly - if it ever came to that being a requirement - would have to deserialize this field in order to access the data.)

If there is anyone that can suggest some alternatives to the aforementioned - in a way that the persistence around my existing classes can be 'swapped out' it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If storing serialized data in a database is the answer, generally, you're asking the wrong question. ;) That's really bad practice and should be avoided if at all possible. That said, I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Are these straight python classes that you're trying to integrate into your Django project?

Comment: Yes they are Python classes. Django's documentation [link]https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/[/link] suggests using a custom model field to seamlessly store and retrieve python objects from the database. My question is what is regarded as best practice in the Django domain of taking a Python class (generated off a UML model class diagram) and integrating that class with the model classes for persistance around those classes. Eg. putting all your methodology in the Django model class could be one way, but what is the best practice?

Comment: Well, best practice, in my opinion, would be to translate the functionality to Django. Short of that, serialization may be your only option, but a shortcut now, will probably lead to more pain in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to move a legacy app to django, I agree with @chrisdpratt and you should try to convert your classes to Django models.  It will require a large effort, so when you are ready, you can follow this trail:

1. **Create a `legacy` app and put your legacy code there.**

   If you decide your code is not so important, and you just want to grab the data, and it is stored in an SQL based server, you can try using [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#inspectdb) to create "legacy models" that will read your data from your legacy server.  I suggest to configure a second DB connection called "legacy" for this. see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

   Create a command line test script to make sure you can load your legacy classes from the database.  (Make sure to set/export environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE from the shell prompt to run scripts from the command line or see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#running-management-commands-from-your-code ).
2. **Create your new django models in a new app ("`myapp`")**.

   Optionally, you can use [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#inspectdb) again to get a basic models automatically from a db.  However, make sure you rename the models to standard Django look and feel and delete any unnecessary fields and attributes.
3. **Create a script which reads the legacy data and writes it to the new models.**
4. **Migrate required logic from old classes to new classes.**

You can use this as a skeleton for the script for step 3:

```
  # legacy/management/commands/importlegacydb.py

  from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
  import myapp.models as M
  import legacy.models as L

  import sys

  write = sys.stdout.write

  def copy_fields(old, new, mapping):
      for old_key, new_key in mapping.items():
          value = getattr(old, old_key)
          if type(value) is str:
              value = value.strip()
          if type(new_key) is tuple:
              value = new_key[0](value)
              new_key = new_key[1]
          else:
              if new_key == "name":
                  value = value[0].upper() + value[1:]
          setattr(new, new_key, value)

  def import_table(old_class, new_class, mapping):
      write("importing %s " % old_class.__name__)
      lookup = {}
      l = old_class.objects.all()
      for old in l:
          new = new_class()
          copy_fields(old, new, mapping)
          new.save()
          lookup[old.id] = new.id
          write (".")
      print " Done."
      return lookup

  class Command(NoArgsCommand):
      help = "Import data from legacy db."

      def handle_noargs(self, **options):
          """
          Read data from legacy db to new db.
          """
          print "Importing legacy data"

          import_table(L.X, M.X, { 'old_field' : 'new_field', 'old_field2' : 'new_field2'})
          import_table(L.Y, M.Y, { 'old_field' : 'new_field'})

          print "Done."
```